# How should I add images using PhoneGap and Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I am new to using PhoneGap for windows phone 7.
I'm not entirely sure what the problem is - when I try to add an existing image, it's not added to the `CordovaSourceDictionary.xml` file, but if I manually add the image to `CordovaSourceDictionary.xml`, it is deleted when I build. How should I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [tutorial](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/windows-phone-phone-gap) by Daniel Egan. Also I have some other links for you

[Tutorial: how to create HTML5 applications on Windows Phone thanks to PhoneGap](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2011/12/23/tutorial-how-to-create-html5-applications-on-windows-phone-thanks-to-phonegap.aspx).
 [Getting Started with Windows Phone](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_windows-phone_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Windows%20Phone).
[Getting Started with Windows 8](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_windows-8_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Windows%208).
[Apache Cordova Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/index.html).

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check image **Build Action** property (Solution explorer, item Properties view). **It must be set to Content**, (when you add image, by default this property value is Resource)

Answer (score 0):

CordovaSourceDictionary.xml is updated by the build process which relies on the way Visual Studio works. You need to trigger a file update, you know, like Right click on the Solution > Add > Add new folder / Existing item etc.

What I do is drag the file from Windows Explorer into the Visual Studio project and drop it in the images folder. NOW Visual Studio knows you have add a new file and when you run the project CordovaSourceDictionary.xml gets automagically updated with your changes.

*Keep up the good fight!*

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't what is breaking your system, but the JS framework I use adds a url query to each image when in a debugging mode (in order to force browsers to reload image, instead of using cached).  So, my image "image/background.jpg" would be accessed as "image/background.jpg?d=34342233".  But, when running on phoneGAP for Windows Phone, it won't recognize the image, and thus it shows up as broken.  So, I had to turn off debugging for the framework I use, and suddenly the images showed up.  Don't forget to set the Build Action to "Content" as mentioned earlier.